# Wait and Notify issue

Tags: java, wait, notify, kdb

Earlier I posted a problem about implementing wait and notify, but I wasn't very clear, so here is a more specific question.

In the long code block below there is one wait and one notify. The notify is supposed to stop the wait and cause it to stop waiting. At the moment, i think the wait works, but the notify does not. Could someone explain why the notify doesn't notify the wait? Thanks!

Note: the rest of the code works i'm only interested in these two specific parts.

```
import com.fmr.ipgt.email.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import org.jdom.Document;
import org.jdom.Element;
import org.jdom.JDOMException;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

class MyQuery {
synchronized void qQuery() throws Exception {
    String query = ".z.k"; // The query that is used to query q; this can be changed here.
    int version = 0;
    c qConn = null;
    qConn = new c(Main.host,Main.port); // Connect to the q database
      while (Main.healthy) {
          Object o = qConn.k(query); // Query q
          version = c.t(o);
          if(!(version==0)) {
              System.out.println(version);
              System.out.println("database healthy");
              NewThread.suspendFlag = false;
              notify(); 
              break; // End the process if the database responds
          }
          }

       System.out.println("reaches loop end");
  }
}

class MyThread implements Runnable {
  MyQuery myResource;

  MyThread(String name, MyQuery so) {
    myResource = so;
    new Thread(this, name).start();
  }

  public void run() {

    try {
      myResource.qQuery(); // Begin a method to query q.
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}

class NewThread implements Runnable {
       String name; // name of thread
       Thread t;
       static boolean suspendFlag;
    private int minutes;
       NewThread(int minutes) {
           this.minutes = minutes;
           System.out.println("reaches constructor");
          t = new Thread(this);
          suspendFlag = true;
          t.start(); // Start the thread
       }
       // This is the entry point for thread.
       public void run() {
          try {
             synchronized(this) {
                while(suspendFlag) {

                   System.out.println("reaches wait");
                   wait(minutes*60000);

                   System.out.println("reaches end");
                   if(suspendFlag) {
                       Main.setHealth(false);
                    Main.sendMessages(); // The database has not responded for the given time. Report that it is unhealthy.
                   }
                   break;
                }
              }
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println(name + " interrupted.");
          } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
       }
    }

public class Main {

private static String[] recipients;
private static String subject = "Database Failure";
private static String message = "The database has failed or is in a hung state";
private static String from;
static String host;
static int port;
private static String emails;
private static int minutes;
static boolean healthy = true;
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    // Import information from the configuration file
      SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
      File xmlFile = new File("/export/home/rhadm/file.xml"); // Note: The directory for the configuration file may need to be changed

      try {

        Document document = (Document) builder.build(xmlFile);
        Element rootNode = document.getRootElement();
        List list = rootNode.getChildren("parameters");
           Element node = (Element) list.get(0);

          host = node.getChildText("host");
           port = Integer.parseInt(node.getChildText("port"));
           emails = node.getChildText("emails");
           String delims = "[ ]+";
           recipients = emails.split(delims); // parse email list
           minutes = Integer.parseInt(node.getChildText("time"));
           from = node.getChildText("from");

      } catch (IOException io) {
        System.out.println(io.getMessage());
      } catch (JDOMException jdomex) {
        System.out.println(jdomex.getMessage());
      }
    MyQuery unhealthy = new MyQuery();
    NewThread ob1 = new NewThread(minutes);
    new MyThread("MyThread", unhealthy);  // Create new Thread


  }
  public static void setHealth(boolean health){
      System.out.println("database unhealthy");
    healthy  = health;  
  }

  public static void sendMessages() throws MessagingException {
        System.out.println("sending emails");
      FCAPMailSender.postMail(recipients,subject,message,from);
  }
  }
```

Comment: i would suggest posting a trimmed down example that still exhibits the issue: no print statements, no exception handling, and if possible no external dependencies. you should be able to get that down to about 10-15 lines.

Comment: @Matthew Do **not** destroy the contents of your question. Leave it "as-is" so other people can benefit from this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are synchronizing on different objects.  The notify will only effect objects synchronized-waiting on the same object & instance.

The waiting thread is synchronized & waiting on a `NewThread` while the notifying thread is doing so on a `MyQuery` instance

Have a shared object.

```
private final Object LOCK = new Object();
synchronized(LOCK){
  LOCK.wait();
}
synchronized(LOCK){
  LOCK.notify();
}
```

Comment: Even better advice is to use a `CountDownLatch` and never again worry about this kind of stuff.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Though its a better idea to use constructs like that it wouldnt work for his example.  Maybe a Phaser?

Comment: I freely admit I didn't invest myself to get to the bottom of that code :) I'm just pretty sure it can be reworked to something from `java.util.concurrent`.

Comment: thanks! i was pretty sure they were synchronized on different objects but I couldn't tell what was synchronized on what. your code also makes sense! only question is where do i put the declaration for lock? in the main method?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I dont blame you! And you're right it can but that would require understanding it all :/

Comment: @MatthewPiatetsky Definitely not the main method, that would make it a local variable. But I see you probably meant the `Main` class. Put it as a `public static final` field there.

Comment: if i try that it tells me LOCK cannot be resolved to a variable in my threads. should i be trying to pass it in as a parameter?

Comment: @MatthewPiatetsky You can as long its the same instance.

Comment: Matthew, you must write `Main.LOCK`.

Comment: thank you! i don't have a chance to test it now but i'm pretty sure Main.LOCK will fix things. Thank you very much for your help!